# MariaDB bad index choosen after threshold

Tags: optimization, indexing, mariadb, threshold

I'm working with MariaDB -> 10.11.4-MariaDB-1:10.11.4+maria~ubu2204

I have a table with :

- 7,984,176 rows
- 2 columns :

  - lab_id (ID of a laboratory)
  - date_prelevement : date of the event from 1 year old to now, every date is distincte
- lab_id is foreign key to an other table ent_laboratoire with 14 distincts values, with this repartition :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZTU5.png)

2 indexes :

```
create index restst_labid on res_ech_test_alex (lab_id);
create index restst_dtprel on res_ech_test_alex (date_prelevement);
```

The query :

```
select *
      from res_ech_test_alex res
          ,ent_laboratoire el 
     where res.lab_id = el.id 
       and res.date_prelevement between ( now() - interval 90 DAY )  
                                and ( now() - interval 70 DAY );
```

90 and 70 are moving.

Results of performances tests :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHPWH.png)

I see a threshold between 17 days and 18 days queried : 1.7 seconds to 16 seconds.

When a FORCE index on date with 18 days of interval -> 1.7 seconds.

How can i change this threshold without FORCE index (because i don't like that and my front dev could not do that with his ORM) ? I thought about optimizer parameters.

Regards,
Alexandre

See description with details.

Comment: "7 98 4176" is a weird way to write a number; is there a missing digit?  "every date is distinct" you mean distinct for a given lab_id?  or distinct in your dataset?  please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table restst_labid` and `explain select ...rest of your query` (for both a slow and a fast query)

Comment: The query does not limit much the number of rows that are retrieved from the table. I would think this query returns a significant number of rows (withink a 20-day range). It's bound to be slow.

Comment: Please don't put tables as images, its hard to read - text and markdown appreciated. You need a compound index `(date_prelevement, lab_id)`.

Comment: Help us help you by providing the requested information